# HTML marqee tag width in 'em' behaves weird

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, styles, width

`Marquee` is one of the most hated tags in `html`, and that hatred probably has roots back in the 90'ies, when everybody had their own web page, and everybody abused this tag.

During my years working as a part-time web designer, I found this tag very useful for some tricks. "Lack of compatibility" is just propaganda against `IE`'s ways (TBH, I don't like `IE` either), because, as far as my tests confirmed, latest versions of `IE`, `FF`, `Opera`, `Safari` and `Chrome` support it.

Nevertheless, I have a problem with my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body, marquee {font-family: courier new; font-size: 30}
   marquee {width: 10em}
   span {background-color: #008000};
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <marquee bgcolor="#800000" direction="left" behavior="slide"><span>1234567890</span></marquee><br>
  12345678901234567890<br>
 </body>
</html>
```

The whole document uses same font face and size, the width of `marquee` element is CLEARLY set to 10em (yes, it gets longer when you increase the number, and yes it is pixel-tiny when you remove the `em`). Whatever value you put there, the width of `marquee` will be 160% of that value.

edit:
My question might be vague and cause some confusion. The green bar should slide in and completely cover the red background. Both `marquee` and sliding `span` should be 10 characters wide (`marquee` is not, that's the problem).

Analyzing very helpful and detailed answer from cale_b, I came to the conclusion that my browsers interpret `width: 1em` as "this element has width of one height of the font currently being in use". An since most of the fonts use golden ratio for width/height proportion, I ASSUME that is the reason why I have 160% increase in length (gr=1.61803).

Do you agree with my conclusion and do you have any idea how to make these two elements the same width in characters?

Comment: "2 lines of pure html" uhm no it is not

Comment: why the long story, could you short it down to the issue only, also a jsfiddle or something would be nice..

Comment: Are you assuming that (a) `10em` must be exactly 10 chars wide and (b) it's only marquee that's screwing up? Here's a marquis + a `10em`-wide div, at the same width. http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/rdqIc

Comment: It's not just a "lack of compatibility", the standard clearly states that it's an "obsolete", "non-conforming' feature. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: @PeeHaa OK, `html` + `css`. Effective lines:
`marquee {width: 10em}`
`<marquee bgcolor="#800000" direction="left" behavior="slide"><span>1234567890</span></marquee>`

@Ronni Skansing http://jsfiddle.net/FWWEn/ - and how many lines is that? BTW, I'm working with an embedded system, every saved byte is important (so you don't get me wrong on so many levels)

Comment: My comment was not about the number of lines, but rather the fact you state "pure html". While `marquee` has never been a standard element in the HTML spec.

Comment: @j08691 I tried so hard not to start a flame. Yes I agree, but for example `ini` is a "de facto" standard, it s depricated, and you shouldn't use it because xml offers so much more. But again, how may applications on an average Windows machine use `ini`s to store config data? There are some thing that just became part of our lives, whether we like them or not...

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find no evidence that the marquee is too wide.

Given the markup you've provided, the default font-size would be 16px, which would result in 1em being equal to 16px (and therefore 10em being equal to 160px).

Here's a great article on the subject: http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates that the marqee at 10em is the same width as a div of the same width **assuming that they have the same font-size applied**.  Note I have updated it to reflect a font size of 20px for demonstration.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJQ9H/1)

However, I do find some issues with the css and markup:

You've got extra closing `</td>` tags in your html.  This suggests you might be using tables for layout, which I would strongly recommend against.

You've got no units on your `font-size: 30` - should that be pixels, ems, points, or ??

**Edit:**
The conclusion you have come to is correct - that 1em is equal to the *height* of the font size, not the *width* of the font size.  That is the case with all browsers.

In order to get the desired width, you'll need to determine the proportion (as you're already hinting at) between the width and height of the font.  **Be aware** that different fonts may have different proportions.

An alternative method would be to set the width on the span as well as on the marquee, and use another technique (such as text-align: center) to make it look good.

Comment: I am sorry for the `</td>`, and yes, this is a part of a bigger data table. (= not used for page formatting) `div`'s can do much more that tables, and are more canonical, but they fail when you need to have an element that will expand and fill the rest of the parent's available height.

`font-size` was just a quick check, to make sure that all elements use same font size. I am aware that I have no units, but let's say its 4pt or whatever, doesn't matter for the test.

Finally, your fiddle gives me the same over-sized `marquee` (div has the same, wrong width as well)

Comment: @Ulrik - Since your font-size was unitless, it was not parsing properly, and therefore the default font size of 16px was being used, which would properly result in 1em = 16px (and 10em = 160px).  I've updated the question and the fiddle to demonstrate this, and provide additional information.

Comment: your input was very helpful, I edited my main question, so please tell me what do you think.

Comment: Again, it looks like I phrased my question in the wrong way.
before `marquee` starts, there should be a red rectangle 10 characters wide. When the thing slides in, there should be a green rectangle 10 characters wide (with text "1234567890" in it) WHICH COMPLETELY COVERS THE RED AREA.
not like this: http://imgur.com/GKKxVgF

Comment: @Ulrik - no, I get that.  The answer addresses that, in trying to get your span and your marquee the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's forget about `marquee` completely.

Have a look at this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {font-family: courier new}
   div  {background-color: #008000}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  This div has width of 10em (ten characters):<br>
  <div style="width: 10em">1234567890</div><br>
  This div contains 10 characters, and is set to be an inline element:<br>
  <div style="display: inline">1234567890</div><br><br>
  They should look the same, don't you think?
 </body>
</html>
```

My assumption is that my browsers interpret `width: 1em` as "this element has width of one height of the font currently being in use", and since most of the fonts use golden ratio for width/height proportions, I have no better explanation for the fact that the width of these two green `div`'s are in golden ratio - 1 : 1.61803.